# What agile method do you use? What agile methods are the most common?

Tags: agile

I am taking a software development class right now and we are discussing agile methodologies.  **What are the most common agile methods?**  I need to look into several and discuss their strengths and weaknesses.  Seems more useful to look into the most prominent methods.

**Observations:**

Scrum seems pretty popular (that is what my team used on two of my coops).

Extreme also seems to get quite a bit of buzz but I am not sure if that many people actually use it.

What does your company use and how do you like it?  Does anyone use:

- Agile Modeling
- Agile unified process
- DSDM
- Essential Unified Process
- Feature Driven Development
- Open unified processes
- Rational Unified Process

Are there other methodologies that I should investigate?

Comment: Is your success metric how popular any given method is, or how well that method solves your programming challenges?

Comment: This should be community wiki.

Comment: I am curious to see what most people are using.

Comment: WIth agile methods it's very hard to separate the hype from the real value. You need to define "most common" very carefully. For example, you could look at adoption ("we are actually using it"), intention ("we will use it soon") or compulsion ("you guys should use it"), and any of these from a technical (programmers) or business (managers) perspective. It's difficult. Scott Ambler runs some interesting surveys on this; see http://www.ambysoft.com/surveys/agileFebruary2008.html for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used SCRUM in personal projects with friends and schoolmates and my current employer uses a custom agile process that's very similar to SCRUM but with fewer meetings.

Answer (score 3):

We have used **Test Driven Development** and **Scrum**.

Answer (score 1):

I've been on some very successful teams which used Scrum very effectively.  It really does help to keep everybody focused and constantly moving forward, and it discourages regressions.

Comment: TDD is also VERY effective, in my own experience.  I have always used a TDD approach and my code tends to generate less bugs than that of my coworkers.